# Tире в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Tags: тире, бсп

Из ответов к упр. Розенталя
"Я, помнится, принимался читать, работать, ничего не клеилось."
По-моему, перед "ничего не клеилось" должно стоять тире, но, почему-то, стоит запятая. Если это не опечатка, помогите, пожалуйста, найти ответ почему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из книги "Призраки" И. Тургенева:

**Я, помнится, принимался читать, работать… ничего не клеилось.**

В авторском тексте стоит **многоточие.** Это означает, что увеличенная пауза делается обязательно, поэтому запятая не подойдет.

**Многоточие можно заменить тире,** которое в БСП  ставится при обозначении противительных отношений (на месте пропуска союза НО).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено **противопоставление** по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз но или а): Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно (Гр.); Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил (Гр.);

Comment: @ Sharon, хотя я с вами согласен, но все же, в БСП вместо при неожиданном присоединении или резком противопоставлении вместо тире возможна запятая.

Comment: А как же мы тогда обозначим резкое противопоставление, запятая с этим не справится. Запятая в БСП ставится или при однородном перечислении, или при неоднородном распространении, когда мы от одной темы переходим к другой.

Comment: Запятая как раз ослабляет оттенок противопоставления.

Comment: Возможно, есть такие примеры, но увеличенную паузу запятая не обозначит, а ведь в данном случае мы говорим о замене двоеточия. И потом это уже учебный пример, который нужно объяснить ссылкой на Розенталя.

Comment: Да. Но ср.: Ещё немного (— ,) и мы оказались бы на краю пропасти;о было возможно (— ,) нет, это уже произошло; Послушать вас (— ,) так вы готовы на всё ради справедливости. Ср. также: И будь не я, коптел бы ты в Твери (Гр.); Захоти он — парню и Тане было бы плохо (Пан.);

Comment: Примеры из справочника Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=190#pp190

Comment: Я могу согласиться с Вами, что тире и запятая могут заменять друг друга, но при замене речь идет о "присоединительном" тире. Это такое универсальное тире, которое и двоеточие может заменять, для него характерен нисходящий тон перед паузой. Но есть еще "разделительное" тире  с восходящим тоном, вот оно и обозначает противопоставление двух частей предложения. Обратите внимание, что в приведенных Вами примерах мы вряд ли можем использовать союзы А и НО.